# C 2D struct array printing strange

Tags: arrays, c, struct, printf

I am working in C with a 2d array of a struct defined as:

```
typedef struct Card 
{
    char word[MAX_LETTERS + 1];
    bool found;
} Card;
```

The array values are being set properly and being based properly to the main function. However, I can't print it the way I want. It will print properly like this

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            printf("%s\n", board[i][j].word);
        }
    }
```

However if I change that to

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            printf("%s ", board[i][j].word);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

It will print one word, and then every few words 1 letter from it, doing this for every column.

Ex output:

```
      Lighthouseall
       Mysteryyrse
       Journeyyinon
        keryhineen
       armony      Keyboard
      Elephanthtty     Discovery
          nyghtne
          tainhtter
         molatetl
       Chocolatety
```

This is my exact function that should be printing it, to see pointers.

```
void printBoard(Card **board, int row, int col) {
    // Print the game board
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            // Check if the word is not empty
            if (board[i][j].word[0] != '\0') {
                // Print the appropriate content based on the card's state
                if (board[i][j].found) {
                    printf("%-*s", MAX_LETTERS, board[i][j].word); 
                } else {
                    printf("%-*s", MAX_LETTERS, HIDDEN); 
                }
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Commenting out all the if statements and the print for `HIDDEN`, it has the same issue.

This is the struct

```
typedef struct Card 
{
    char word[MAX_LETTERS + 1];
    bool found;
} Card;
```

`MAX_LETTERS` is 3 larger than the longest string word is being set to.

It should print in a format like:

```
****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           
****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           
****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           
****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           
****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           
****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           
****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           
****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           
****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           
****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****           ****
```

But instead of ****, words. (This is the same function I am using, but instead of board[i][j].word, it is using the asterisks.

Comment: Please revise question to provide a [mre] i.e. a program.  Hard-coding a test case is a very powerful way of communicating what you are doing.  Incomplete snippets means we have to do a lot of work to compile your code.  Why do repeat the struct declaration to us?

Comment: There are 3 versions of the print statement.  Why do hard-code the magic value 10 in the first two?  Your code seem to use variables (good).

Comment: Check if your words have ANSI escape codes, for example `\r\n`.

Comment: printf format specifier %s is for printing null terminated strings.